# Syncfusion map not getting refreshed while map layertype change in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, maps, syncfusion, xamarin-forms-4

I am using syncfusion map in xamarin forms. I need to change its layer type that is street and satellite. When I change street to satellite then it works fine but again I go to change from satellite to street map does not get refreshed. Please suggest any workaround.

I tried increase decrease geocoordinates and zoomlevel but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

On investigating the reported issue using a simple sample on Android, iOS, and UWP platforms, found that it was working fine for me. I tested it by dynamically changing the LayerType, and the map was perfectly refreshed. I have attached a tested sample and the output video for all the platforms below for your reference.
Please get the sample and the output video from the below repository - [sample link](https://github.com/VishalOmprasad/Sample)